# a pun in an extract from John Oliver's Standardized Testing

Tags: meaning

Being a non native English speaker, I'm struggling with an extract from John Oliver's [Standardized Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6lyURyVz7k) (16'14 -> 16'26) :

> And I do not wanna hear, what the French kids think about (those ?)
>   results : "All this time and all this money, and your race to the
>   top is been(???)... how would you say... a [???] joke on a treadmill(???)...

Several words are inaudible to me and I don't understand the final pun.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Mostly correct just missing 'meandering jog': 'And I do not wanna hear, what the French kids think about _those_ results : "All this time and all this money, and your race to the top is been, how would you say, a meandering jog on a treadmill"  '. He then follows with what I think is 'boeuf', French for beef.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELU is not a transcription service

Comment: @Mitch: I used to hear "exclamatory" **Boff!** quite a bit when I lived in France back in the early 70s. It was just a discourse marker, something like a "verbalised shrug".

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...mutated through Oliver's accent and my ears.

Comment: He didn't ask us to transcribe it.  He asked us to explain a pun.

Comment: @WillBriggs It's not a pun.

Comment: Well, I *thought* it was a pun... if this thread is off-topic, please feel free to close it.

Comment: Now it's a (potential?)  mondegreen.

Answer (score 1):

This is with reference only to what you typed.

A race to the top is, obviously, a competition, striving to be the first to reach a goal.  But running on a treadmill, you never get anywhere:  you keep running but stay in one place, never approaching a goal, or anything else.

Something being a joke can mean not that it's funny, but that it's ridiculous or stupid.  In this case, thinking you're making progress toward a goal, while you're actually running in place, as on a treadmill.